# If $p \ge 5$ is a prime number, how to show that $p^2 + 2$ is always divisible by $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> If $p \ge 5$ is a prime number, how to show that $p^2 + 2$ is always divisible by $3$?

Please let me have a clear proof based on simple number theory.

Comment: Hint: Use modular arithmetic. What number can $p$ not be $\mod 3$? Then what must $p^2+2$ be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $p$ is a prime number which is *not* a multiple of $3$, $p$ can be written as $3k\pm1$, for some $k$. But then $p^2+2=9k^2\pm6k+1+2=9k^2\pm6k+3=3\times(3k^2\pm2k+1)$.

Comment: This proves that $p$ doesn't need to be prime, just that it is not a multiple of $3$.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Fermat's Little Theorem.

$a^{q-1} \equiv 1 \pmod q$ (where $q$ is a prime that does not divide $a$).

In particular, $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.

Now substitute $a = p$. Since $p$ is a prime greater than $3$, it satisfies the non-divisibility criterion.

$p^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$

So $p^2 + 2 \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Among any three consecutive numbers $x-1,x,x+1$ exactly one is divisible by $3$

Since $p$ is not divisible by 3 then $p-1$ or $p+1$ is divisible by 3, so their product $p^2-1$ is also divisible by 3. and since 3 is divisible by 3 so is their sum $(p^2-1)+3 = p^2+2$ divisible by 3.